# Amount of reputation from answer upvotes reduced?

Tags: support, answers, votes, reputation

Has the amount of reputation received from upvotes to answers been reduced from +10 to +5. I only received +5 rep for each upvote on my answer to [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33700/synthesis-of-phenoxyacetone-from-phenol/33713#33713) question. Is this a new feature or a bug?

I suspect this is a bug because I also just discovered a -15 on the same answer in my rep tab with no apparent reason attached (there are no downvotes).

[image]

Comment: O.O Can you tell us what you see in the reputation tab? Screenshots, data, anything.

Comment: I think the 'unaccept' you got may have something to do with it

Comment: @santiago Aha that explains it. Just me being silly though although I would have expected to get a notification for being unaccepted.

Comment: Not silly at all - I agree, it would be helpful to see such a notification

Comment: Once you are able to accept your answer, the "[SOLVED]" will be implied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @santiago for pointing out the reason. The fives crept in because the answer was accepted and then later unaccepted for the -15. Strangely though, I didn't get a notification for being unaccepted - maybe this could be implemented.

Comment: No, this isn't strange at all. The devs decided that a negative change in rep not be visible unless you gain new rep points that outweigh the loss. For example, you lost 15, didn't get a notification for it. You gained 30, but instead, you saw a +15 in your rep bar. This is just as designed.